# Adoptable Storage Problematic

Tags: internal-storage, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

Hi I have and LG G4 Beat with 8 GB storage . After factory reset that device only have 2.5 GB free space . So I don't have free space for applications . I am using adoptable storage function . But some of the applications for example emulators need faster storage . Even an UHS-1 card didn't fix my problem . So without root how I can write my files to internal storage again . Seems only some applications installable to there . Which folder in internal storage is writable ? How I can see it when using adoptable storage function ?